# Rooting nexus 4 failed

Tags: rooting, nexus-4

I was trying to root my nexus 4 by the following steps:

- Download and copy the file `UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.43.zip` to /sdcard/
- Download the file CWM 6.0.3.5
- Got into Fastboot/Bootloader Mode on Nexus 4
- Execute the command `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.3.5-mako.img`
- Choose RECOVERY from the Fastboot menu and enter Recovery Mode
- In ClockworkMod recovery “flash zip from SD card”
- Then selected “choose zip from sdcard”
- Now I should see the copied file `UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.43.zip` but there was none, and I got the output `Can't mount /sdcard/

Then I tried to use `Install zip from sideload`

- I sent the file with `adb sideload UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.43.zip`
- I get the output:

  ```
  Restarting adbd...
  E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install`
  E:failed to open last_install: Invalid argument
  Finding update package...
  Opening update package...
  Installing update...
  ***********
  SuperSU installer ZIP
  ***********
  Mounting /system, /data and rootfs
  Disabling OTA survival
  Removing old files
  Creating space
  Extracting files
  Restoring files
  Setting permissions
  Unmounting /system and /data
  Done
  ```

Then I go back and choose `reboot system now` but when booting only the GOOGLE sign pops up and then the X (I was waiting for about an hour)

**SOLVED**
I did a full reset by downloading the original factory image from google 
[here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

And then I followed the steps in this tutorial:
[here](http://smart-phones-how-to.blogspot.it/2013/05/how-to-root-nexus-4-windowsmac.html)

Comment: I don't know about your method, which seems pretty complicated and you might have done something wrong. But [here](http://www.android.gs/root-google-nexus-4-on-official-android-4-3-jwr66v-jelly-bean-firmware/) is the method I've followed and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Trust me my friend, using Wug's Nexus Root Toolkit v2.1.4 is the way to go with ALL nexus devices. Double check your drivers too (toolkit will do this)

Comment: Put the Solved part in an answer, and copy down relevant details from the links to prevent a link rot. Then after 2 days, accept your own answer.