# How to run TWRP recovery headless?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have samsung s5 having damaged screen. Its screen is blank and touch is not working. I have checked USB debugging by connecting to tv via hdmi to enable adb and flashed  twrp ecovery `twrp-3.2.1-0-k3gxx.img.tar` from [here](https://dl.twrp.me/k3gxx/) via odin. 
It installed successfully as blank TWRP folder is created. But I am unable to access recovery using adb as mentioned in this [guide](https://www.pocketables.com/2014/10/using-twrps-new-adb-interface.html). It shows no device in  `adb devices`.

How can I enable adb in twrp recovery if it is not enabled by editing twrp settings file or some other way.

Comment: Did you enable [USB debugging](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Screenshot_20160419-094739.png)? Enabling ADB and recovery is not the same

Comment: Yes. I have already enabled usb debugging under Developer options. But I want to enable twrp recovery adb also called openrecoveryscript commands so that I could fire command directly to flash zip.

Comment: Then smth is wrong with your phone except broken screen. TWRP command will work out-of-the-box on working ADB. For example, see [this](https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/issues/146)

Comment: Don't confuse chicken and an egg: ADB should be enabled **before** TWRP, not another way.

Comment: I have run twrp in other devices in which it asks "Swipe to Allow system modifications" when twrp recovery is booted for the first time. Is this preventing adb from running ?

Comment: No, this message simply states that your partitions are to be mounted r/w. It has nothing to do with ADB.

Comment: I have checked USB debugging by connecting to tv via hdmi to enable adb. But I can't see and control anything in recovery mode via hdmi.

Comment: If your phone is rooted, install [Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and boot into TWRP by typing `reboot recovery` in terminal

Comment: Here is the .twrps file, I found inside TWRP folder :: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ccvdMFmwEWD4JaARXP5qzGbQyzK0yuo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am doing all this just to root my phone. Inside recovery, I would fire command to flash supersu zip file .

Comment: No way. You are out of the luck. However as a last resort you can try to boot into TWRP from fastboot ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113535/94888), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51178/94888)) and try to flash supersu blindly. Though I dunno how it will help you in your case

Comment: I have finally rooted my S5 by flashing `CF-Auto-Root-k3g-k3gxx-smg900h.tar` from `https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/` via odin .   Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Post it as answer, if you will be successful with TWRP.